# The outlined text trace is 0.01m below the other traced objects when importing svg in blender

Tags: svg

I have traced an image and also added text and traced text outline in Adobe Illustrator. The output svg looks good but has a problem when import in blender.

The text part is slightly below the other traces. I have to manually bring it up. Since I have many svg files to work with it takes a lot of time.

I have even tried Inkscape. Same problem when reading in blender.[image]

Thank You

Comment: Hello RS, I see this has come up before, and the problem wasn't very well expressed the first time round, so I'm reluctant to call it a duplicate. But you can help us out greatly by creating a .blend with 2 or 3 examples of the unsatisfactory .svg  imports, and sharing it on https://blend-exchange.com/ . (Edit the lprovided link into your post). Then maybe one of us can help you out by devising a method you can use simultaneously on multiple imports.

Comment: Thank you Robin, I have uploaded the .blend file